# Rotating a rectangle

Tags: trigonometry

Lets say we have a rectangle with *height* `h` and *width* `w`. If we rotate it by `d` *degrees*, what would be the *width* and *height* of the window to display it without any clipping? I mean what is the formula to calculate `wh` and `ww`?

[image]

Comment: How much trigonometry do you know? Do you know how to calculate the  short sides of a right-angled triangle given the length of the hypotenuse and one of the acute angles? That's all you need here (after you split $ww$ and $wh$ into their two parts).

Comment: Looking at the picture, $wh$ would be $w \sin(d) + h \cos(d)$. This holds when $0^\circ \le d \le 90^\circ$.

Comment: @TonyK - Next to none ;)

Comment: @J.J. - Thanks. Why don't you put that as an answer?

Comment: @Majid: Someone else might, I'm a bit busy. And it's not complete: You got to be careful if $d$ doesn't lie in the range I gave. I suspect there will be four cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
wh(d) = \begin{cases} 
h \cos(d) + w \sin(d), & \mbox{if} \;\; 0^\circ \le d \le 90^\circ \;\; \mbox{or} \;\; 180^\circ \le d \le 270^\circ \;\;  \\
w \cos(d-90) + h \sin(d-90), & \mbox{if} \;\; 90^\circ \le d \le 180^\circ \;\; \mbox{or} \;\; 270^\circ \le d \le 360^\circ \;\;   
\end{cases}
$$

$$
ww(d) = \begin{cases} 
h \sin(d) + w \cos(d), & \mbox{if} \;\; 0^\circ \le d \le 90^\circ \;\; \mbox{or} \;\; 180^\circ \le d \le 270^\circ \;\;  \\
w \sin(d-90) + h \cos(d-90), & \mbox{if} \;\; 90^\circ \le d \le 180^\circ \;\; \mbox{or} \;\; 270^\circ \le d \le 360^\circ \;\;   
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The [solution of Jiri](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49020/rotating-a-rectangle/49041#49041) results in negative sizes for angles in the third and fourth quadrant.

This calculation, using the absolute sine and cosine values, works for all angles:

$$
wh(d) = h \; |\cos(d)| + w \; |\sin(d)|
$$

$$
ww(d) = h \; |\sin(d)| + w \; |\cos(d)|
$$